# How do I send text messages to the notification bubbles?

Tags: python, notify-osd

I wrote a python code for getting random text into a .txt file.
Now I want to send this random text into notification area via 'notify-send' command.
How do we do that?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

We can always call **notify-send** as a subprocess, e.g like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess

def sendmessage(message):
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', message])
    return
```

Alternatively we could also install [python-notify2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/python-notify2) or [python3-notify2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/python3-notify2) and call the notification through that:

```
import notify2

def sendmessage(title, message):
    notify2.init("Test")
    notice = notify2.Notification(title, message)
    notice.show()
    return
```

Comment: I had to use `subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', message])` to make the first example work.

Comment: The second one a `pynotify.init("Test")` and `pynotify.Notification(title, message).show()`. By the way I'm „Learning Python The Hard Way”, so I might just overlook something...

Comment: So sorry for that. I was unable to test this earlier on my box at work - my bad. Edited the missing bits in.

Comment: There is a `notify2` package in Python 2.7.12 as well so might as well use it on Ubuntu 16.04 as well 18.04 and 20.04 so you don't have to modify your code.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: thanks for the notice - included :)

Answer (score 14):

### python3

Whilst you can call `notify-send` via `os.system` or `subprocess` it is arguably more consistent with GTK3 based programming to use the Notify [gobject-introspection](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Notify-0.7) class.

A small example will show this in action:

```
from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import Notify

class MyClass(GObject.Object):
    def __init__(self):

        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        # lets initialise with the application name
        Notify.init("myapp_name")

    def send_notification(self, title, text, file_path_to_icon=""):

        n = Notify.Notification.new(title, text, file_path_to_icon)
        n.show()

my = MyClass()
my.send_notification("this is a title", "this is some text")
```

Comment: Not just more consistent with Gtk programming, but also it's a single process: there's no fork-exec  going on, so no waste of resources on spawning new process just to send a notification bubble, plus `Popen()` will call shell to run the command, so there's shell process popping up too.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Using Gtk when you don't need to requires a lot of work. Much simpler to install `python-notify2` or `python3-notify2`. As for `Popen()` the newer `subprocess` methods (using `popen`) allow you to turn off the shell which is a security risk at times. I probably could have worded this better but I'm still learning python.

Comment: From the link you've posted, you can also find [`Gio.Notification`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/Notification.html#Gio.Notification). I think they are separate? When would you use one or the other?

Answer (score 8):

To answer Mehul Mohan question as well as propose the shortest way to push a notification with title and message sections:

```
import os
os.system('notify-send "TITLE" "MESSAGE"')
```

Putting this in function might be a bit confusing due to quotes in quotes

```
import os
def message(title, message):
  os.system('notify-send "'+title+'" "'+message+'"')
```

Comment: You could suggest [an edit to that post.](http://askubuntu.com/posts/479244/edit)

Comment: What about using `'notify-send "{}" "{}"'.format(title, message)` rather than adding strings?

Answer (score 7):

You should use [notify2](https://notify2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, it is a replacement for python-notify. Use it as followed.

```
pip install notify2
```

And the code:

```
import notify2
notify2.init('app name')
n = notify2.Notification('title', 'message')
n.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import os
mstr='Hello'
os.system('notify-send '+mstr)
```

Comment: How do I customize this notification? Like heading, image in notification, etc.?

Comment: This version is vulnerable to arbitrary command execution.

Comment: If my edit is approved, I fixed the security problem

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking at this in +2018, I can recommend the [**notify2**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/notify2/) package.

> This is a pure-python replacement for notify-python, using python-dbus to communicate with the notifications server directly. It’s compatible with Python 2 and 3, and its callbacks can work with Gtk 3 or Qt 4 applications.

Answer (score 2):

[PyNotify2](https://bitbucket.org/takluyver/pynotify2/src/master/), suggested by many answers, [considers itself as ***deprecated***](https://notify2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as of late 2020:

> notify2 is - or was - a package to display desktop notifications on Linux. Those are the little bubbles which tell a user about e.g. new emails.
>
> notify2 is deprecated. Here are some alternatives:
>
> - [desktop_notify](https://pypi.org/project/desktop-notify/) is a newer module doing essentially the same thing.
> - If you’re writing a GTK application, you may want to use GNotification ([intro](https://developer.gnome.org/GNotification/), [Python API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/Notification.html)).
> - For simple cases, you can run `notify-send` as a subprocess. The [py-notifier](https://pypi.org/project/py-notifier/) package provides a simple Python API around this, and can also display notifications on Windows.

So, given the above suggestions:

- The `notify-send` subprocess approach is already explained in other answers, and
  [py-notifier](https://pypi.org/project/py-notifier/) can simplify that, with an added bonus of working on Windows platforms using [win10toast](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/), but also with all the drawbacks of a subprocess call under the hood:

```py
from pynotifier import Notification

Notification(
    title='Notification Title',
    description='Notification Description',
    icon_path='path/to/image/file/icon.png',
    duration=5,
    urgency=Notification.URGENCY_CRITICAL
).send()
```

- [desktop_notify](https://pypi.org/project/desktop-notify/) seems to use DBus directly, just like `PyNotify2`, and has `dbus-next` as its sole dependency.

```py
notify = desktop_notify.aio.Notify('summary', 'body')
await notify.show()
```

- [fossfreedom's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/479458/11015) covers GTK's `gi` introspection route. But please note he uses a different API than the one mentioned above:

  - There's the [`Gio.Notification`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/Notification.html) API, from Gio 2.4 onwards, mentioned by `pynotify2`
  - And there's the [`Notify`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Notify-0.7) API, from GLib 2.0 onwards, used in @fossfreedom's code snippet.